# Calculate the rate between two numbers (Thumbs up/down Rating)

Tags: php

What is the mathematical solution/algorithm for thumbs up/down rating system? I want to display the rating like the one we usually see on the tube sites like:

Thumbs up btn | Ratings here | Thumbs down btn

but i'm not sure what calculation to use. I tried the:

Thumbsup / Thumbsdown * 100 but it gives me result morethan 100%.

```
Example: 6/2*100 = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some thumbsup or some thumbsdown (if not then displaying a percentage would make no sense)

For the percentage Thumbs up:

Thumbsup / (Thumbsup + Thumbsdown) * 100

So in your example

```
6/(6+2) * 100 = 75%
```

And likewise with Thumbsdown as the numerator for the percentage thumbs down

Comment: ugh that ninja.

Comment: Which may cause DivisionByZeroException.

Comment: Wow that was fast Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`thumbsUp / (thumbsUp + thumbsDown) * 100` gives the ratio for thumbs up.

`thumbsDown / (thumbsUp + thumbsDown) * 100` gives the ratio for thumbs down.